# How pass the data corresponding "submit" buttons in a dynamically generated jsp page

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a jsp page which has a "submit" button next to the "Item Url" which can be directed to another jsp page. It will look like below:

|Item1 | Item Url_1 | "Submit Button" for line 1
|Item2| Item Url_2 | "Submit Button"  for line 2

I am attaching part of my code which generates the items with the "submit" buttons. How can I pass the Item which corresponds to the respective Item number?

Thanks

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.sql.*"%>
<html>
<body bgcolor="pink">
<h2>Stage 2</h2>
<h3>Product URL List</h3> 
<form action="frame4A.jsp" name="myform" target=frame4 method="POST">
<%
    try {
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    out.println("<h1>Driver not found:" + e + e.getMessage() + "</h1>" );
    }
    try {
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection (
    "jdbc:postgresql://*****/****",
"postgres", "*****" );

    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs;

    rs = stmt.executeQuery("select laptopname, laptopurl from selectedproduct ");


    out.println( "<table border=1>" );


    while ( rs.next() ) {
        String lName= rs.getString("laptopname");
        String laptopUrl = rs.getString("laptopurl");

        out.println("<tr><td>"+lName+"</td><td><a href="+laptopUrl+"     target=\"_new\">"+laptopUrl+"</a></td><td><input type=\"submit\" name=\"reviewItem\" value=\"Reviews\"></td></tr>");
}
    out.println( "</table>" );
    conn.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
out.println( "<h1>exception: "+e+e.getMessage()+"</h1>" );
} 
finally{

}
%>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I identified your problem correctly, you can handle this in many ways such as

- Add a hidden input field in the corresponding form that will be appended to the GET request upon the click of the button.
- If you are using JavaScript to submit this form, you can do something like this in your JSP:

> `"<input type='button' onclick='handle(" + itemid + ")'>"`

Then write a JavaScript function called handle()

```
function handle(id){
     //proceed to submit the form
}
```

Comment: The javascript function does not seem to get called at all.                                         out.println("<tr><td>"+lName+"</td><td><a href="+laptopUrl+" target=\"_new\">"+laptopUrl+"</a></td><td><input type='submit' name='reviewItem' onclick='reviewURL("+lName+")' value=\"Reviews\"></td></tr>");

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    function reviewURL(goUrl) {
    document.myform.urlSelected.value = goUrl;
    document.myform.submit();
    }
    </script>

Comment: Since lName is a string and not an integer (like in my example), it has to be put in the quotes. Else it will be handled as a variable name. So it will be `'reviewURL(\""+lName+"\")'`